# Why does my Apps Script reference the wrong row?

Tags: google-apps-script

#### The Goal

I am trying to create a spreadsheet using some custom functions.  The purpose for the sheet is to keep score in a quizzing competition.  The top row has the question number, the second row the score, and the third number the number of fouls for that question.

#### The Problem

After noticing some problems with the score calculation, I was able to narrow the problem down to the part of the code where I add up the fouls that occurred prior to the current question.  It seems that no matter what I do, the code sums over the question row, not the foul row.

#### Attempted Solutions

The extremely strange thing is that no matter what I change the reference cells to, it always produces the same result (i.e. it still references the question row same as it always has).

#### Example

I'm not sure if that makes any sense, but I've made an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FCZFS-4drrb_4jltD45_XoPjjoZ931Eq1i0v1czCydA/edit?usp=sharing) so you can see what I'm talking about and try to figure out what is going on.  Keep in mind that I'm well aware that I could accomplish what I'm trying to do in the example sheet with a simple built-in formula, but since there's no way to use worksheet formulas on the Apps Script side, I have to create my own version of it.  I've made the example editable for anyone with the link, so you should have full access to it; but if you have problems, just let me know, and I'll see what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your For loop, you are summing the indexes rather than the values:

Try:

```
  for (var PrevValue in PrevValues[0]) {
    Sum = Sum + Number(PrevValues[0][PrevValue]);
  }
```

EDIT:
You'll also need to account for the case where you pass in a single cell rather than a range (=mySum($B4:B4)), because in that case the value is passed directly instead of an array.

```
  if(PrevValues instanceof Array){
    for (var PrevValue in PrevValues[0]) {
      Sum = Sum + Number(PrevValues[0][PrevValue]);
    }
  }else
    Sum = PrevValues;
```

Comment: Ah! Well, I guess once again I've been caught in the trap of thinking myself to be infallible and discovering that, amazingly enough I'm not. :-) Whatever the case, I suppose it's clear that I don't have much experience with JavaScript. I've done some stuff with Python, but I suppose it's a bad idea to carry assumptions over. Thanks for the help!